# Is there a way to (helpfully) give feedback on QGIS Training Manual?

Tags: qgis, documentation

I'm just working my way through some of the current QGIS Training Manual:
  http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/training_manual/

As I work through it I am coming across occasional things which are out-of-date with the current version or are clearly errors. Is there a place and a way to send feedback (that is in a useful form)? I'm not looking to take on the rather involved task of "contributing to this manual" as outlined in section 19 (Appendix) and don't really want to join a high-traffic documentation developer email list, but hoped that a bit of user feedback might be helpful.

As examples of the sort of feedback I have..

1. The official exercise data download already has many of the exercises completed, so it is difficult to do the exercise as written:
   http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/training_manual/foreword/preparing_data.html
2. In section 6.3.1 (Using QGIS’ Form Design Functionality), the "Open Feature Form" checkbox has moved to the "identify results" window after version 2.2. (The workflow suggested for this new implementation is discussed here: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Identify-results-form-vs-feature-form-td5158186.html )

Comment: Have you considered just filing these as issues https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues

Comment: GIS Stack Exchange users Nathan Woodrow (nathan-w) and moderator Anita Graser (underdark) would be able help (or have the contacts) make these changes..

Answer (score 7):

In addition to my earlier comment about filing your examples as issues on [qgis/QGIS-Documentation GitHub](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues)

The other thing you might want to consider is actually change the documentation yourself, see the QGIS documentation [A Step By Step Contribution](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/documentation_guidelines/first_contribution.html) for details of how to do this.